# CSS animation affecting page width

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an image spinning on my page using CSS animation transforms. The problem is when I reduce the page width I get a horizontal scroll bar that's constantly changing sizes. How can I keep the spinning image but have the parent container cut off the sides when it starts expanding outside of the page width?

I've tried changing the image to a background-image in the **rays** div but then I lose the effect completely.

See the below minified example.

```css
#rays-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 490px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
#rays {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rays {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes rays {
    from {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.spin {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-animation: rays 60s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: rays 60s infinite linear;
    -ms-transform-origin: center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="rays-container" class="spin">
  <div id="rays">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/af/97/ee/af97eef70a8bce541b19c6a41178a015.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpJbYG)

Comment: overflow:hidden on the container.... but you need to make the container static width. Atm it changes to the content.

Comment: if you change the #rays to have class 'spin' insteadof the container it works. with overflow hidden

Comment: Not sure why you are using width and height for the image, position: absolute for the parent div, and width and height: 100% for the div containing the image. Removing these things and adding `overflow-hidden` to the parent div will make it much better.

Comment: @dragonvsphoenix that could work but it cuts off the image when the page is large enough to show the whole thing.

Comment: @Julsy The image has a height and width so the axis stays in the center when spinning. The parent div has an absolute position because it's behind other elements on the page.

Comment: maybe use the same principle. make a container that is 100% of the width of the page and make sure that the container has overflow:hidden.

Comment: @dragonvsphoenix Yeah that's a good idea, the problem is when I change the width to 100% the image is no longer centered on the page. Still working with it though.

Comment: position fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scroll bars you're seeing are because the content inside it is larger than its width (that's the obvious part). That being said, one way of fixing it would be to add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the CSS of the parent of your element with `class="spin"`, which in this case is the `<body>`.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Overflow is the CSS property that defines what will happen if the content doesn't fit. The value `hidden` tells it to simply clip the content, and not display any scroll bars.

For more info, here's the [MDN page on CSS overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Comment: Wow, looks like this worked. Instead of putting it on the body I ended up putting it on the parent container outside of #rays-container. Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `padding` to the `#rays` class, like so.

```
#rays {
    padding: 100px;
    /* as suggested by Matheus Avellar */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* width: 100%; */
    /* height: 100%; */
}
```

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMLMJj)